# Modalsätze: dadurch, dass

Tags: context

Warum wird "dadurch, dass" in diesen Sätzen benutzt?

> - Dadurch, dass mein Job langweilig und schlecht bezahlt ist, bin ich sehr demotiviert und habe starkes Heimweh.
> - Dadurch, dass ich nach kurzer Zeit aufgebe, wird auch mein Lebenslauf sicher nicht attraktiver für einen zukünftigen Arbeitgeber.
> - Dadurch, dass Hamburg in der Nähe des Meeres liegt, ist die Luft hier frisch und sauber.

Theoretisch gesehen, man versteht unter "dadurch, dass" - wie man das Ziel erreichen kann (Wie? Wodurch? Auf welche Art und Weise). Aber hier erkenne ich kein Ziel und keine Lösung, wie man dieses Ziel erreichen kann. Und ich muss sagen, dass in diesem Kontext "daduch, dass" "weil" ähnelt.

Answer (score 4):

Die Einteilung der adverbialen Nebensätze in kausale, konditionale, finale usw. dient nur der groben Orientierung. Am Ende wird man sich die genaue Bedeutung eines einzelnen Konnektors wie *dadurch … daß* anhand vieler Beispiele erarbeiten müssen. Dabei wird man feststellen, daß der Konnektor auch kausal verwendet werden kann, wie die Beispiele in der Frage zeigen.

In der Duden-Grammatik wird *dadurch … daß* als *modal-instrumental* bezeichnet. Ein Beispiel, bei dem *weil* nicht passen würde, ist:

> Er entschuldigte sich dadurch, daß er ihr einen Blumenstrauß überreichte.

Der Blumenstrauß ist hier sicherlich nicht der Grund für die Entschuldigung, sondern das Mittel, mit dem diese zum Ausdruck gebracht wird.

Anstelle von *dadurch … daß* kann man auch *indem* verwenden.

> Er entschuldigte sich, indem er ihr einen Blumenstrauß überreichte.

Um zu verdeutlichen, wie unangenehm Konnektoren für Sprachlerner sein können, sei noch darauf hingewiesen, daß *indem* auch die Bedeutung von *während* haben kann. Dieser Gebrauch ist nicht mehr zeitgemäß, begegnet einem aber noch in Romanen.

> "Heute singen die kleinen Vögelchen ein trauriges Lied", sagte er, indem er sich setzte.

Vielleicht noch zwei Beispiele, bei denen ein kausaler Konnektor nicht durch *dadurch … daß* ersetzt werden kann.

> Ihm wurde gekündigt, weil er Gelder veruntreut hatte.

Da das Mittel der Kündigung – die schriftliche Mitteilung – feststeht, paßt nur der rein kausale Konnektor *weil*.

> Zieh dich warm an, denn es wird kalt!

Die Kälte ist hier der Grund dafür, den Imperativsatz zu äußern. Also etwa:

> Zieh dich warm an! Ich sage das, weil es kalt wird.

Man nennt das illokutive (auf den Sprechakt bezogene) Kausalität. In der gesprochenen Sprache würde man *weil* in diesem Fall mit einem Verbzweitsatz verbinden.

> Zieh dich warm an, weil es **wird** kalt!

*Dadurch … daß* kann keine illokutive Kausalität ausdrücken.

Comment: Sehr gute Beispielsätze!

Answer (score 2):

Letztlich geht es um die Präposition *durch*, die hier als Pronomen *dadurch* auftritt. *Durch* gibt hier die *Ursache* an. Es geht also um Kausalität.

Beispiel ohne Nebensatz:

> Durch starken Regen war der Boden aufgeweicht.

In den Beispielsätzen könnte auch *weil* benutzt werden:

> Weil mein Job langweilig und schlecht bezahlt ist, bin ich sehr demotiviert und habe starkes Heimweh.
>
> Weil ich nach kurzer Zeit aufgebe, wird auch mein Lebenslauf sicher nicht attraktiver für einen zukünftigen Arbeitgeber.
>
> Weil Hamburg in der Nähe des Meeres liegt, ist die Luft hier frisch und sauber.